# Триггер при удалении записи

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Необходимо сделать триггер , который при удалении записи из таблицы занесет эту запись в таблицу архив.
Я делал так

```
create trigger yyy on Выпуски_журналов
for delete as

declare @Идефикатор int;
select @Идефикатор = Идентификатор_выпуска from Выпуски_журналов;
begin
if @Индефикатор in (select Индентификатор_выпуска  from Выпуски_журналов where Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=Год)

    insert into Выпуски_журналов_архив values((select  Идентификатор_выпуска from Выпуски_журналов ),
    (select  id_журнала from Выпуски_журналов ),
    (select  Номер_выпуска from Выпуски_журналов ),
    (select Год from Выпуски_журналов )
    );

else
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'вы не можете удалить этот выпуск'

end;
```

Удаляю так

```
delete Выпуски_журналов
where (Идентификатор_выпуска=48)
```

Из основной таблицы запись удаляется , но в таблицу архив вносится последняя запись в таблице(например хочу удалить выпуск с Идентификатором 48 , из основной таблицы удаляется правильная завпись , но в таблицу архив заносится запись с Индентификатором 52(последняя запись в таблице))
Может кто-то знает почему так происходит?

Comment: Как насчёт [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Необходимо сделать триггер , который при удалении записи из таблицы занесет эту запись в таблицу архив.

Демка:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, val INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT, val INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,11), (2,22), (3,33);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
ON t1
FOR DELETE 
AS
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM DELETED;
```

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 33 |

| id | val |
| --- | --- |

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id > 1;
```

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 33 |
| 2 | 22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCIhUtbY)